# Spring Cloud Data Flow in a Kerberos Enabled Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, hadoop-yarn, spring-cloud-dataflow

Will spring-cloud-data-flow-yarn and the hdfs sink work in a kerberos enabled Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0):

> SCDF on YARN:

Please review the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_configure_kerberos) on how you would configure to enable Kerberos on SCDF's YARN implementation.

> hdfs-sink:

If you're running this application in SCDF's YARN implementation with the above configurations, the Kerberos settings will be automatically applied.

However, if you'd want to use `hdfs-sink` in non-YARN environment (*eg: cf, k8s, ..*), you would apply [similar configurations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#literal-spring-hadoop-security-literal-configuration-properties) - they can be passed as in-line properties in SCDF's stream definition DSL.